# OBSOLETE - achivy.com, track all your statistics, reputation and badges in one place (now also supports coderwall)

Tags: app, badges, obsolete, ruby, reputation-graph

[image: achivy logo]

## About

#### Time to collect your achivies

[Achivy](http://achivy.com) adds some fun to your life. It supports [Stack Overflow](http://achivy.com/apps/stackoverflow) and all Stack Exchange applications, [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub),[Coderwall](http://achivy.com/apps/coderwall) [Ohloh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohloh) as well as many other applications to your profile to see how many achievements, badges, and scores you have and follows your progress. You can keep up with your friends, and see the other people’s achievements and activities - **achivies**.

- Achivy provides you to see your and your friends’:
- Achievement "badges"
- Achievement levels and scores
- Statistics and reputation tracking on charts
- Top and recent users for all applications
- Share you badges via Twitter and Facebook as you get them.

#### Web Site

- http://achivy.com
- [Stack Overflow Page](http://achivy.com/apps/stackoverflow)

#### Platform

Works on all browsers.

## Contact

Any ideas or comments? Please email achivyapp [at] gmail.com. We will get you back immediately.

## Code

Ruby on Rails

Stack Exchange API 2.0
**Profile Page**
[image: Altuure profile]

**Statistics Tracking**
[image: Stats tracking]

Comment: update:
now achivy can tweet and post on facebook as you get badges !!!! check notifications after login http://achivy.com/account/settings 
PS: dont forget to add twitter and facebook as connections

Comment: achivy.com has mobile support now

Comment: [coderwall](http://achivy.com/apps/coderwall) support added !!!

Comment: Interesting. Any future plans to support all SE sites?

Comment: achivy supports all stackexchange sites...  http://achivy.com/apps

Comment: if it fails to connect your stackexchange accounts ,please use manual connect wizard  http://achivy.com/wizards/stackapps :( sorry but this is a bug in stackexchange http://stackapps.com/questions/2989/why-arent-all-of-my-accounts-showing-up-in-the-users-id-associated-route

Comment: Thanks @altuure - using this wizard, I got error "something went wrong please try again"