# Is it possible to get daily reputation change for a user via the API?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-deferred, api-v2

I'm trying to fetch a user's daily reputation change history for a project that's still early in the planning stages.  I've been trying to use the "reputation" endpoint, but it seems like I can query globally and lose the per-day information, or query with date restrictions and get one day at a time - therefore getting each day's reputation change would require potentially hundreds or thousands of queries and processing.

The [reputation graph](https://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph) script seems to scrape the data off the user's reputation page, but is there an "API method" of getting this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation history with perfect accuracy isn't something we actually have a fast way to generate at the moment.

There is some work under way to make such information available for other purposes, it will probably be exposed as part of a future API revision.

Comment: Currently I'm pulling this data from the user's reputation graph by reading and parsing a page from their profile.  It's a little kludgey, but if you guys don't have a problem with it, I can keep doing it this way until API n+1.

Answer (score 0):

you can track that on [achivy.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/2920/achivy-is-just-released-supports-all-stackexchange-applications) with stats and charts

[achivy.com stackoverflow page](http://achivy.com/apps/stackoverflow)